# How can I limit HTML Tags to a Div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

If I'm embedding content in HTML, how can I ensure that any HTML in that content only affects the embedded content?

For example:

```
<strong>Hello this is a code,<br>,<i>Yeah,...
```

When I embed that content, everything on the page after the content will be styled because the content contains open tags without close tags (`</strong>`, `</i>`)

How can I limit the effect of these tags?

I don't mind the content having tags, but I want them only to affect the content, not the rest of the page the content is embedded in.

PHP allows "auto-close tags", but I want a safe way in jQuery or PHP to limit HTML to a an area on a page.

Comment: The string will be load with the database with php.

Comment: show us your code, i can't know how the page is created.
all text inside strong tag will be strong.

if you can choose what HTML tags will be in your code, just close your strong tag: <strong>Strong text</strong>

Answer (score 1):

HTML by nature only allows HTML tags within a div. Those tags will always be able to have content in them though. For example, if you attempt to output into a div something like:

```
<br /><br /><span>Malicious <?php include('malicious.php'); /> file!</span>
```

The HTML will render *everything* inside the `div` tag as either HTML *or* raw text, and will only attempt to render anything it recognises as valid HTML.

It will get loaded into the DOM as:

`<div><br /><br /><span>Malicious <?php include('malicious.php'); /> file!</span></div>`

It will get shown on the page as:

```
 
 
Malicious <?php include('malicious.php'); /> file!
```

By 'auto close tags' in PHP I assume you're meaning something like:

```
<?php
$fragment = '<p>Opened paragraph <a href="#">opened linked';
$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($fragment,array('show-body-only'=>true),'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
?>
```

If you forcibly close your tags in PHP, they will get outputted correctly in the HTML in reverse order:

```
<p>Opened paragraph <a href="#">opened linked</a></p>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want with HTML or CSS -- you'll need something that can parse any HTML in the content and close any open tags or you, like the example given by [Obsidian Age](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2341603/obsidian-age).